# Page Admin Managers

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am the manager of two other Pages but I can't seem to add any Managers on the MacArthur High School Football Parents Association 2013 page that I created for our Football Booster Club.  I've put my email while signed into the page as a manager and it says either my email is wrong, I'm already a manager or it can't find the email I'm trying to add.

Please help! I've tried adding a couple of other email addresses also and same thing.  I have gone into my FB and liked the page, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

On your facebook, go to the top right click on the `gear`. Then select the page you want to edit. On the page, click `edit page - manage admin roles` and you should be able to manage the managers.